# creating objects within a block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

```
[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [[myTreeNode mutableChildNodes] addObject:[NSTreeNode treeNodeWithRepresentedObject:obj]];
        //myTreeNode is an NSTreeNode
    }];
```

Is it ok to create objects from within a block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's basically OK to do anything in a block that you might do in a normal function.